# Skype don't work on RHEL (CentOS)

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have downloaded `rpm` installer file of `skype` from official site and installed it like this:

```
$ sudo yum install skypeforlinux-64.rpm
```

Now I'm trying to launch `skype` from desktop icon, but it don't start. Also I tried to launch it from terminal, and got same result, as from user, as from root.

What can it be?

System: both RHEL and CentOS with Xfce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed `skypeforlinux` in terminal directly from it's folder (from user)

```
$ /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux
```

and got this error:

> The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /usr/share/skypeforlinux/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.

**Solution:**

```
$ sudo chmod 4755 /usr/share/skypeforlinux/chrome-sandbox
```

---

<sub>See also: repository with old versions of `rpm` packages [skype-stable](https://repo.skype.com/rpm/stable/skype-stable.repo)</sub>